# syntastic not working on macvim, but works perfectly fine on the terminal

Tags: macvim, plugin-syntastic, path

I have an issue where in MacVim, I don't get any syntastic/eslint related functionality.  When I run `!which eslint` in macvim, I get "eslint not found" - eslint is definitely installed.

[image: eslint not found on macvim]

If I run `!which eslint` on iTerm, I get the correct location of eslint (`/Users/fpe/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/eslint`).

It looks like MacVim is not aware of my `$PATH`. I didn't set anything specifically.  I am also using zsh, if that makes a difference.

How do I fix this?

Comment: They are both different.

Comment: If you're using zsh as your login shell, and setting PATH in .zprofile, consider adding `-l` to [`'shellcmdflags'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shellcmdflag%27) so that it runs a login shell and sources `.zprofile`

Comment: Hmm yes that didn't help @muru

Comment: Can set the path in macvim manually?

Comment: Sure: `let $PATH .= ":/some/path"` will append `:/some/path` to `PATH`.

Comment: I now get the error `/bin/zsh: can't open input file: which eslint`

Comment: If you modified `shellcmdflags`, maybe undo that.

Comment: great, I get `which eslint` working now with a hardcoded PATH :)

Comment: I usually set `PATH` in `.zshenv` for this reason - it affects *every* invocation of zsh.

Comment: I tried that, but will have a look into it later. Thanks for the help!